# Seleccionar table y que autosume

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo un datatable con datos de cantidades pero quiero cuando yo seleccione una dicha cantidad de la tablas este autosume. Algo muy parecido a excel `SUM`.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
select: true
});
} );
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>




<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr id="EncabDespachos">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Pedido</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Real</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="pedido" class="pedido" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text">10</td>
  <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text">10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="pedido" class="pedido" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="text">20</td>
  <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text">15</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Sumar total<h3/> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="autosum" autocomplete="off">
```

Adjunto una foto. Si selecciono una x cantidades de Row este me deberia sumar en el input de abajo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos

Comment: ¿Podrías describir mejor lo que quieres conseguir? No entiendo bien el sentido de tus palabras: "quiero cuando yo seleccione una dicha cantidad de tablas este autosume". ¿Qué seleccionas? ¿Cómo? Gracias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Adjunte una foto. Seleccionando una x cantidad este me autosume en el input de abajo

Comment: Por lo pronto a tu código le faltaría indicar la opción `{ select: true }` en la creación (`$('#myTable').DataTable();`) para activar la selección de celdas. Voy a redactar una respuesta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Muchas gracias agradecido

Comment: Hecho. Cuando puedas comprueba mi respuesta y si tienes alguna pregunta no  dudes en hacérmela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para conseguir lo que deseas debes conocer lo siguiente de DataTables:

- Selección de celdas usando la extensión [`select`](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/).
- Búsqueda de celdas seleccionadas con [`cells()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells()).
- Obtención de los datos mediante [`data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()).
- Uso de las funciones de reducción de datos con [`reduce()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/reduce()).

Un ejemplo de cómo hacer lo que deseas (ver comentarios en el código) es:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  /* El estilo "os" es el más parecido al Excel */
  let tabla = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    select: {
      style: 'os',
      items: 'cell'
    }
  });
  /* Esta función actualiza la suma cada vez que cambiamos la selección */
  function actualizar() {
    /* Calculamos la suma mediante una función de reducción */
    let suma = tabla.cells( { selected: true } )
      .data()
      .reduce(function (a, b) {
        let x = parseInt(a) || 0;
        let y = parseInt(b) || 0;
        return x + y;
      }, 0
    );
    /* Asignamos al campo del formulario el resultado obtenido */
    $('input[name="autosum"]').val(suma);
  }
  /* Aquí es donde configuramos los eventos para que llamen a la función de actualización */
  tabla
    .on( 'select', actualizar )
    .on( 'deselect', actualizar );
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- necesario para la función de selección -->
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">




<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr id="EncabDespachos">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Pedido</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Real</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-name="pedido" class="pedido" data-type="text">001</td>
  <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text">10</td>
  <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text">10</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-name="pedido" class="pedido" data-type="text">002</td>
  <td data-name="Item" class="Item" data-type="text">20</td>
  <td data-name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad" data-type="text">15</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Sumar total<h3/> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="autosum" autocomplete="off">
```